# C# creating a class derived from an abstract and singleton class

Tags: c#, inheritance, singleton, multiple-inheritance

```
public class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    // this is my singleton class
}

public abstract class A : Singleton<A>
{
    // this is my base abstract class. 
}

public B : A
{
    // I want this class to be derived from A, also to derive from Singleton and MonoBehaviour
}``
```

Since c# does not support multiple inheritance. I am trying to make a class which is derived from class A and singleton class. When I call an instance of B. It creates an instance of A and that gives a null exception. Is there a solution for this or do I have to use interface ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: singleton doesn't give you that much, just a static member and an instance getter... could just implement that in the class.

Comment: An interesting read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036883/can-i-define-an-abstract-class-for-all-derived-singletons-in-this-way?rq=1

Comment: Singleton isn't a type of object so much as it is a coding pattern. You use a Singleton to gain the "global" accessibility of static objects while still having the benefits of instances. There's no need to create a `Singleton` class to implement that kind of behavior.

Comment: to make a singleton class you should make its constructor private. then use non-private property to get instance of class using singleton pattern. like this `public  Singleton<T> Instance => _instance ?? _instance  = new Singleton()`

Comment: Also Singletons should be sealed, since inheritance is to be avoided in this pattern.

Comment: Indeed. It should not be possible to inherit from a singleton because it then becomes possible to subvert the intent of the singleton by making a derived class with no implementation overrides that would allow the instantiation of a second instance of the same class.

Answer (score 2):

**The first question is** : What do you want to share between this classes ?

Waiting this answer, I will try to give you a generic explanation with as much detail as possible.

**1 - Sharing only methods**

If you want to share only methods, the best practice is to use Interfaces to split your logic as you want and give it to concrete classes :

```
public interface IInterface1{
//some methods
}


public interface IInterface2{
//some methods
}

public class MyClass : IInterface1, IInterface2{

}
```

**MyClass** can be abstract if you want and you can put some methods as virtual to override them if you want too

**2 - Sharing methods and properties**

You will do it from the same way, but the Interfaces need to be added to the correct class

```
 public interface IInterface1{
    //some methods
    }


public interface IInterface2{
//some methods
}

public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
//some methods and properties
}

 public class MyClass : MyAbstractClass, IInterface1, IInterface2{

    }
```

You can add the interfaces to **MyAbstractClass** instead of **MyClass**, it depends your architecture and your needs

**3 - Singleton**

For the singleton, as say in the comments, this is only a way to gain global accessibility, so you need to do it in your *"last"* class, here **MyClass**

I Hope I expressed myselft enought correctly for this explanation and I hope this answer will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will share methods and properties between classes. So I will go with your second option. But that's where my problem begins I want to derive that class from another singleton class too. But I think that's not possible as I understand it returns an abstract reference from singleton pattern. You suggest that, to make that class also singleton I have to implement it inside MyClass, right ?

Comment: The thing is that an abstract class can be singleton because an abstract class cannot be instanciated. Furthermore, you will use at least only you inherited class so this is the one that needs to be singleton. If the singleton is a class that is already developped by someone else, i think the best is to isolate the things that you need into a superclass and inherit it from the singleton and your new class